# LCS-PS101 print server installation on Windows10

Tags: printing, printer

I encour a problem that my client had old computers with Windows XP and he was using them only for login to remote host.
Things changed and now he buy new computers with Windows 10.
We setup all others things only we stick with using LCS-PS101 print server with HP1320.
They use them for about 10 stations to print envelopes.

We do not change setup on LCS-PS101 print server.
We are able to add this device with using HP UniversalPrinter Driver.

The problem is that finally printers do not prints anything.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem so that Windows10 will work properly with this printing hardware?

Comment: The LCS-PS101-2 is a small, handy print server for printers with a USB connection. ... dot matrix printers to networks with up to 10 or 100 Mbit/s    ....  This is a really old print server.   Consider a much newer print server. So also is the HP1320 an older printer.  It may need to be upgraded.

Comment: This ^^^It's probably using the old SMB1.0 protocol that is no longer supported in Windows 10. While considering a modern replacement (preferable) try setting it to use other protocols and adjust the clients' settings accordingly.